# Odoo: how to filter values from related project_task_type

Tags: dns, odoo

In Odoo, I inherited the "project" model and made some small changes.

Project model in my module:

```
class project(models.Model): 
    _inherit = "project.project"
    _columns = {
    'is_project' : fields.boolean("Is project", default=True)
 }
class project_task_type(models.Model):
    _inherit = "project.task.type"
    _columns = {
    'task_type_is_project' : fields.boolean("Is project", default=True)
}
```

Relation beetwen `project_project` and `project_task_type` in original project module:

**project_project**:

```
'type_ids': fields.many2many(
    'project.task.type', 'project_task_type_rel', 'project_id',
    'type_id', 'Tasks Stages',
     states={'close':[('readonly',True)], 'cancelled':[('readonly',True)]}),
```

**project_task_type**:

```
'project_ids': fields.many2many(
    'project.project', 'project_task_type_rel',
    'type_id', 'project_id', 'Projects'),
```

In original form view :

```
<record id="edit_project" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">project.project.form</field>
   <field name="model">project.project</field>
   <field eval="2" name="priority"/> 
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      [...]
      <page string="Project Stages" attrs="{'invisible': [('use_tasks', '=', False)]}" name="project_stages">
         <field name="type_ids"/>
      </page>
      [...]
```

So my question is how to filter `type_ids` records to get values from `project_task_type` where `task_type_is_project = False`.

I added domain attribute to field with name "type_ids"

```
<field name="type_ids domain="[('type_id.task_type_is_poject','=',False)]"/>
<field name="type_ids domain="[('task_type_is_poject','=',False)]"/>
```

but without success.

I  will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: The solution is to add a domain to the type_ids field in the view. Add what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

> I added domain attribute to field with name "type_ids"
>
> ```
> <field name="type_ids domain="[('type_id.task_type_is_poject','=',False)]"/>
> <field name="type_ids domain="[('task_type_is_poject','=',False)]"/>
> ```
>
> but without success.

The second way is the correct one, the domain operates on the model of the field, so `project.task.type`, which means you should directly filter on its fields, in this case `task_type_is_project`. There is no `type_id` field.

The only problem I see is a typo: you forgot a **r** in p**r**oject.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake but in my code there is no error. The second way unfortunately didn't work. I have no idea why....Despite this, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Did you reload your module after making the changes? Did you check (using debug mode -> fields view get) that the "new" view (the one with the domain) is displayed?

Comment: Yes I did. In "field view get" my field looks like: <field name="type_ids domain="[('task_type_is_poject','=',False)]" modifiers="{'readonly': [['state', 'in', ['cancelled', 'close']]]}"/> I didn't add "modifiers" attr and I haven't this in my code